# How fast could the Amazon rainforest regrow after deforestation?

Tags: botany, ecology, forestry

We hear a lot about clear-cutting of the Amazon rainforest and how that affects climate change. However, are there any studies on how fast areas of rainforest can regrow or the ecosystem can recover if left alone after logging or slash and burn agriculture? It is often discussed how many ecosystems can rapidly recover after human exploitation stops (e.g., temperate forests). However I don't know if that would apply to the Amazon because rainforest soils are so nutrient-poor after slash and burn agriculture.

Comment: depending on the type of deforestation possibly never. slash and burn rainforests often don't recover.

Comment: Plants can regrow in a matter of weeks, months, years, depending on species. However, I encourage you to review secondary succession as well as second growth forests vs old-growth forests. All forests are not created equal. Just b/c plants regrow, doesn't equate to the Amazon "forest" (in its current state) having returned. Its current (perhaps already *former*) state will likely never regrow (in fact, there is almost 0 chance). But any similar analog would take 100s or more likely thousands of years to establish.